# How to define module level variables in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, variables, drupal-7

How to define variables in drupal module so that I can access those variables in that module from any function

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `global` ? `$_SESSION` ?

Answer (score 5):

Try [variable_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)() and [variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)()

Set the variable like that:

```
// I have assumed the variable name to be "the_name_of_the_variable"
variable_set("the_name_of_the_variable", "the value of the variable");
```

And then retrieve the value like that:

```
$my_variable = variable_get("the_name_of_the_variable", "a default value in case the variable has never been set before");
```

Comment: `variable_get()` already handles the condition of the variable never been set, by offering the default value option. Surely you can handle that by coding using `global`, but it can never get easier than the one-line `variable_get()`.

Comment: The problem with variable_get/set is that you are storing these values in DB, which may not be needed in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

For every page load in Drupal all the `.module` files are loaded. But this is not the case for the `inc` files.

Inc files are loaded only when it is mentioned in the menu hook or they are explicitly mentioned in module file using module_load_include

```
// Load node.admin.inc from the node module.
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
```

I think this pretty much answers your question. So you should define your variables as global in these files.

By your question if you mean that the scope of the functions defines in your module also should be limited to your module only, then I don't think there is any solution as of now. But at-least the above method will make sure that your variables are not loaded, when your module is not performing any actions.